# Find and replace substring in line of file

Tags: python

I have a file like this(I'm using a copy of fstab as file):

```
# <file system>        <dir>         <type>    <options>             <dump> <pass>
UUID=121231414142              /media/data  ntfs3      defaults              1      1
UUID=2321231414142             /media/data2 ntfs-3g      defaults              1      1
UUID=451231414142              /media/data3 ntfs3      defaults              0      0
UUID=455612314141              /media/videodisk ntfs3    defaults              0      0
```

What I want is to find a line by giving the mount point (e.g /media/data) and on that line to replace the module(If is ntfs3 to ntfs-3g, if it's ntfs-3g to ntfs3)

I tried this:

```
with open(filepath, "r") as file:
        lines = file.read()
        if (mountpoint + "  ntfs-3g") in lines:
            print("ntfs-3g")
            lines=lines.replace(mountpoint + "  ntfs-3g", mountpoint + "    ntfs3")
        elif (mountpoint + "    ntfs3") in lines:
            lines = lines.replace(mountpoint + "  ntfs3", mountpoint + "    ntfs-3g")
            print("ntfs3")
        print(lines)
```

But this replaces also lines with data2 and data3.
So how can I replace only the specific line and also how to write the changed string back to the file?

Comment: Can you show better your original file and the expected output?

Comment: You have two variables called `filename` and `filepath`, and I'm suspecting that you mixed the two up in a few cases.
Also, please tell us their values you set up, and an expected / actual output!

Comment: I edited my question, so I hope is more clear. The filepath variable is the path to fstab file. The filename(I changed it to mountpoint) variable is the mountpoint which I get from a list with all the mount points from fstab. So If the given mount point is /media/data2, I want in that line to change the module from "ntfs-3g" to "ntfs3"

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, in fact, the code does not replace anything when I run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a [regex search-replace using a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```py
import re

with open(filepath, "r") as file:
    lines = file.read()

    def swap(match):
        mount, driver = match.group(1), match.group(2)
        replaces = {
            "ntfs-3g" : "ntfs3",
            "ntfs3" : "ntfs-3g",
        }
        new_driver = replaces[driver]
        # error out if the driver is not expected
        return f"{mount} {new_driver}"
    lines = re.sub(f"({mountpoint})\W+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)", swap, lines)
    print(lines)
```

Basically a simple regex matching the mountpoint + whitespaces + driver combo, passing those to a function that creates the replacement string.

### Edit

Edited code, replaced `\w+` with `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` because `\w` did not include dashes.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a right approach, but I get an error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/ch-fstab.py", line 87, in <module>
    get_file_line()
  File "/home/user/ch-fstab.py", line 67, in get_file_line
    lines = re.sub(f"({mountpoint})\W+(\w+)", swap, lines)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 209, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/home/user/ch-fstab.py", line 64, in swap
    new_driver = replaces[driver]
KeyError: 'ntfs'

Comment: @dancer_69  should be fixed now, added note on what changed